# Component Teams or Feature Teams

Tags: structure, agile

I am an experienced product person however I keep on finding myself in the same old argument component teams or cross-functional feature teams.

What are the pros and cons of Feature and Component teams?

Does its matter at what stage of growth the business is?

A common argument against feature teams is that there is no single ownership of services is this a problem? in my mind specializing is not a good idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Cross-functional feature teams:

- Few external dependencies
- Able to directly equate the work they do to customer value
- Rarely a bottleneck or lacking in work
- Challenges balancing the load on specialists in the team
- Specialists in the team may feel 'isolated' from others with similar skill sets

Component teams:

- Often have external dependencies or other teams depend on them
- Hard to evaluate their work as it is a piece in the puzzle rather than end user value
- Lots of team members with similar skill sets, so knowledge sharing, etc. is good